# Storing user activity in embedded array versus separate collection?

Tags: mongodb

Say I want to mirror a social media's news feed by storing it in a mongo collection, and then periodically syncing it to fetch updates.

Multiple users will then be able to interact with this feed at a time (both reads and writes)

Also, lets assume that I initially will be storing between 500 and 1000 entries, but that I might consider increasing this later on.

My question is, would i be better off storing these activities in an embedded array, or a separate collection

As I understand it, storing it in an embedded array will allow for quick access access, but can quickly halt performance due to memory allocation.

On the other hand, storing each entry as it own document means ill have to go fetch every single on of them, which will slow down read performance

Any suggestion to what might fit my usecase best is much a appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection. Queries return matching documents, not matching array elements, so the things you are searching for should logically be your collection documents. You can reshape a document to contain just the first matching array element when a query matches against elements of an array, but not, e.g. the first 4 matching elements. You would need to use aggregation for simple queries, which would hurt performance.